# ATTiny1616 writing the SUT fuse in SYSCFG1 with AVRDude Command Line

Tags: programming, attiny, avrdude

I want to write the SUT fuse in SYSCFG1 to be 0x0 for 0ms startup time as per page 40 of the datasheet:

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATtiny1616-3216-DataSheet-DS40001997C.pdf

I am using the following command to look at the ATTiny1616 fuses but I am not sure which fuse I should write as I don't see any named SYSCFG1:

```
avrdude.exe -c jtag2updi -p attiny1616 -P com9 -U fuses:r:-:i -v -C ..\etc\avrdude.conf -b 19200
```

Which is giving me the following output:

```
avrdude.exe: Version 6.3-20190619
             Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
             Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

             System wide configuration file is "..\etc\avrdude.conf"

             Using Port                    : com9
             Using Programmer              : jtag2updi
             Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
JTAG ICE mkII sign-on message:
Communications protocol version: 1
M_MCU:
  boot-loader FW version:        1
  firmware version:              6.00
  hardware version:              1
S_MCU:
  boot-loader FW version:        1
  firmware version:              6.00
  hardware version:              1
Serial number:                   00:00:00:00:00:00
Device ID:                       JTAGICE mkII
             AVR Part                      : ATtiny1616
             Chip Erase delay              : 0 us
             PAGEL                         : P00
             BS2                           : P00
             RESET disposition             : dedicated
             RETRY pulse                   : SCK
             serial program mode           : yes
             parallel program mode         : yes
             Timeout                       : 0
             StabDelay                     : 0
             CmdexeDelay                   : 0
             SyncLoops                     : 0
             ByteDelay                     : 0
             PollIndex                     : 0
             PollValue                     : 0x00
             Memory Detail                 :

                                      Block Poll               Page                       Polled
               Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
               ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
               signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               prodsig        0     0     0    0 no         61   61      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               fuses          0     0     0    0 no          9    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               fuse0          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               fuse1          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               fuse2          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               fuse4          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               fuse5          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               fuse6          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               fuse7          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               fuse8          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               data           0     0     0    0 no          0    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               usersig        0     0     0    0 no         32   32      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               flash          0     0     0    0 no      16384   64      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               eeprom         0     0     0    0 no        256   32      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

             Programmer Type : JTAGMKII_PDI
             Description     : JTAGv2 to UPDI bridge
             M_MCU hardware version: 1
             M_MCU firmware version: 6.00
             S_MCU hardware version: 1
             S_MCU firmware version: 6.00
             Serial number:          00:00:00:00:00:00
             Vtarget         : 5.0 V

avrdude.exe: jtagmkII_initialize(): Cannot locate "flash" and "boot" memories in description
avrdude.exe: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.16s

avrdude.exe: Device signature = 0x1e9421 (probably t1616)
avrdude.exe: reading fuses memory:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.28s

avrdude.exe: writing output file "<stdout>"
:09000000000002FF00C70300002C
:00000001FF

avrdude.exe: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FF, H:FF, L:FF)

avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.
```

Is it possible to write the SYSCFG1 fuse with a command parameter like:

```
-U <fusenamehere>:w:0x0:m
```

Or do I need to look at some other way of doing this?

**EDIT**
Some more background. I have been using the Arduino IDE to write the programs and program the 1616 with ElTangas' jtag2updi on an Arduino UNO.

Comment: Any help? https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tiny1616-fuse-setting-error

Comment: Hi @awjlogan I had seen that article in my google searches this morning, however as I am not using Atmel studio to program the chip it didn't solve my particular problem. Thank you for the link though.

Comment: no problem, sorry, just a very quick skim of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered in the boards text for the board defintion in the Arduino IDE the following line:

```
atxy6.bootloader.SYSCFG1=0x03
```

So I have been able to amend this line to set the fuse as required.

**EDIT**

Well I can only give more detail from a windows perspective:

- I found this file by opening the Arduino IDE. Going to File => Preferences.
- In the dialog that opens you will see at the bottom a link to your preferences.txt (e.g. C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Arduino15\preferences.txt. Click this and it opens location of the file in file explorer.
- From here go into: packages => megaTinyCore => hardware => megaavr => 1.1.4 (or whatever version you have).
- In this folder you will see boards.txt.
- Close the arduino IDE and then edit boards.txt. In this file you can find the line: `atxy6.bootloader.SYSCFG1=0x03`. This is the line I changed to `atxy6.bootloader.SYSCFG1=0x00` to change the SYSCFG1 fuse for SUT0.

Hopefully this is a little more helpful.

Comment: It would be nice if you could describe the solution you found in more detail. This would be a bit hard to follow.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys - I have edited my answer. Hopefully, it makes it a little clearer.

Comment: And you then just choose Tools -> Burn Bootloader in the Arduino IDE and it works, right?

Comment: Correct. I believe you need to restart the IDE for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. As you can see when you used the verbose mode it listed all the fuses you have : fuse0, fuse1, fuse2 ...
If you type `avrdude.exe -c jtag2_updi -p attiny1616  -U fuse0:r:-:i -v`   it will show you the value written in fuse 0 which is the WDTCFG fuse.

So fuse0 to fuse9 correspond respectively to fuses with offset 0x00 to 0x09 (page 33 in attiny1616's datasheet http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATtiny1616-3216-DataSheet-DS40001997C.pdf)

SYSCFG1 fuse corresponds to fuse6 and normally you can write in it with the command `avrdude.exe -c jtag2_updi -p attiny1616  -U fuse6:w:0x00:m`
You can do so with all the fuses, for LOCKBIT you juste replace "fuseN" by "lock".

Comment: Hi @FF504. Thanks for the answer. I tried this, or something like this originally and bricked my 1616, so I probably did something wrong. If I get time I will check using your answer and let you know how it goes.

Comment: You must have touched a critical bit of a fuse, for example, with a bad manipultation you can lock your microcontoller when modifying mistakenly the fuse OSCCFG (fuse2).

Comment: Quite probably. I've yet to try changing the fuse this way again because it's now in the bootloader we burn but I imagine I tried doing the wrong fuse, or burnt another fuse as well.